# Quick search - how to use attributes via parameters ?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have this working in advanced search :

`catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=vanille&is_bio=1`

Every product whose name contains "vanille" and attribute "is_bio" set to true will appear.

Now since I need to search not just in "name" but also other fields like "brands", I have to use quick search and its "q" query (correct me if I'm wrong). But in this case attributes won't have any effect :

`catalogsearch/result/?q=vanille&is_bio=1`

Will show every products containing "vanille" whatever the value of "is_bio".

Is there anyway to activate params in quick search ?

Comment: Create your custom controller with custom filter. What is your search engine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. You need to go `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` and locate your attribute. Make sure the configuration for `Use in Search Results Layered Navigation` is set to `Yes`:

[image: Screenshot of attribute configuration]

However, note the warning underneath the option:

> Can be used only with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price.

This means that if you are currently using a Yes/No attribute type **you will need to create a new Dropdown type attribute**.

Once you have your attribute set to be used in layered navigation, you can then use it as a filter in your URL, e.g. `catalogsearch/result/?q=vanille&is_bio=123` (where `123` is your "Yes" attribute option ID).

**There is a caveat to changing from Yes/No to the Dropdown type.** If you are using this attribute elsewhere in your codebase, you will no longer be able to use the `getIsBio()` method to test for true/false:

```php
if ($product->getIsBio()) {
    // won't work for Dropdown types
}

if ($product->getAttributeText('is_bio') === 'Yes') {
    // works for Dropdown types
}
```

Comment: Question is for magento 1.9

Comment: @GopalPatel thanks for the heads up! Have updated my answer.

Comment: question is regarding catalog search and your answer providing information on b=navigation filters. `is_bio` is working in advance search means it is searchable attribute.

Comment: @GopalPatel Layered navigation can be used to filter catalog search results. Advanced search is a completely different configuration to layered navigation.

Comment: Upps sorry got confused between my current project's requirement and this question

Comment: @DannyNimmo thank you for your answer. I will try your solution in a few minutes and come back after this.